Can you have sections of the chordDiagram that don't connect to anything?
I have made a chordDiagram for two datasets, each of which contain 'modules' that are named with a colour. The links show how modules from dataset1 overlap with modules from dataset2. However, in reality, not every element of a module in dataset1 overlaps with modules in dataset2. Currently, the chordDiagram just shows the size of each module as the total of the elements that overlap with modules in dataset2. In reality module size is perhaps twice that. Is it possible to have each segment of the circle represent the true size of the module, rather than just the elements that overlap with modules in dataset2. Here is an example below, but any help making the segment size reflect the actual module size, rather than just the total of the elements that overlap would be great!
full_size1 <- c(black = 795L, blue = 4433L, brown = 4383L, cyan = 201L, green = 1209L, 
greenyellow = 319L, grey = 538L, grey60 = 152L, lightcyan = 165L, 
lightgreen = 138L, lightyellow = 109L, magenta = 438L, midnightblue = 197L, 
pink = 542L, purple = 340L, red = 1012L, royalblue = 74L, salmon = 254L, 
tan = 310L, turquoise = 5949L, yellow = 2391L)
full_size2 <- c(black = 1289L, blue = 2324L, brown = 1861L, cyan = 205L, darkgreen = 64L, 
darkgrey = 56L, darkorange = 50L, darkred = 75L, darkturquoise = 59L, 
green = 1660L, greenyellow = 443L, grey = 245L, grey60 = 141L, 
lightcyan = 183L, lightgreen = 138L, lightyellow = 137L, magenta = 848L, 
midnightblue = 190L, orange = 53L, pink = 911L, purple = 539L, 
red = 1345L, royalblue = 89L, salmon = 222L, tan = 322L, turquoise = 2679L, 
white = 48L, yellow = 1690L)

comparison_table <- structure(c(0, 0, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 45, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 55, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 25, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17, 19, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 0, 184, 0, 
0, 98, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 73, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 
0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60, 0, 0, 
0, 33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
51, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 
179, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
72, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 
0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 
0, 0, 0, 0), dim = c(15L, 24L), dimnames = structure(list(c("black1", 
"blue1", "brown1", "cyan1", "green1", "greenyellow1", "grey601", 
"lightgreen1", "magenta1", "pink1", "purple1", "red1", "tan1", 
"turquoise1", "yellow1"), c("black2", "blue2", "brown2", "cyan2", 
"darkgreen2", "darkgrey2", "darkorange2", "darkred2", "green2", 
"greenyellow2", "grey2", "grey602", "lightcyan2", "lightgreen2", 
"lightyellow2", "magenta2", "orange2", "pink2", "purple2", "red2", 
"royalblue2", "salmon2", "tan2", "white2")), names = c("", ""
)), class = "table")

colour_vector <- c(black1 = "black", blue1 = "blue", brown1 = "brown", cyan1 = "cyan", 
green1 = "green", greenyellow1 = "greenyellow", grey601 = "grey60", 
lightgreen1 = "lightgreen", magenta1 = "magenta", pink1 = "pink", 
purple1 = "purple", red1 = "red", tan1 = "tan", turquoise1 = "turquoise", 
yellow1 = "yellow", black2 = "black", blue2 = "blue", brown2 = "brown", 
cyan2 = "cyan", darkgreen2 = "darkgreen", darkgrey2 = "darkgrey", 
darkorange2 = "darkorange", darkred2 = "darkred", green2 = "green", 
greenyellow2 = "greenyellow", grey2 = "grey", grey602 = "grey60", 
lightcyan2 = "lightcyan", lightgreen2 = "lightgreen", lightyellow2 = "lightyellow", 
magenta2 = "magenta", orange2 = "orange", pink2 = "pink", purple2 = "purple", 
red2 = "red", royalblue2 = "royalblue", salmon2 = "salmon", tan2 = "tan", 
white2 = "white")

chord_title <- "My comparisons"

# Clear existing circos plot to reset parameters
circos.clear()

# Set gap degrees for sectors
circos.par(gap.after = c(rep(1, length(rownames(comparison_table)) - 1), 10, rep(1, length(colnames(comparison_table)) - 1), 10),
           canvas.xlim = c(-1.2, 1.2), # Adjust x-axis limits for more space
           canvas.ylim = c(-1.2, 1.2)) # Adjust y-axis limits for more space

# Create chord diagram
chordDiagram(comparison_table, 
             transparency = 0.5, 
             grid.col = colour_vector,
             annotationTrack = "grid",
             preAllocateTracks = list(track.height = 0.2))

# Add custom tracks and annotations
circos.trackPlotRegion(track.index = 1, panel.fun = function(x, y) {
  xlim = get.cell.meta.data("xlim")
  ylim = get.cell.meta.data("ylim")
  sector.name = get.cell.meta.data("sector.index")
  circos.text(CELL_META$xcenter, ylim[1] + cm_h(2),sector.name,
              facing = "clockwise",niceFacing = TRUE, adj = c(0, 0.5))
  circos.axis(h = "bottom",labels.cex = .6,sector.index = sector.name)
}, bg.border = NA)

# Add the title
title(chord_title)


I've tried googling and AI, but no joy on getting it working.

Don't know if technically possible, not implying that it's not. One approach could be to define 2 additional blocks, 1 per dataset for the parts that don't overlap and have the sections without intersection point to the respective block. Kinda making them point back to the dataset where they come from

Solved it like this:
# Clear existing circos plot to reset parameters
    circos.clear()
    
    # Set gap degrees for sectors
    circos.par(gap.after = c(rep(1, length(rownames(comparison_table)) - 1), 10, rep(1, length(colnames(comparison_table)) - 1), 10),
               start.degree = -90, # Rotate the plot so that the first sector starts at the top
               canvas.xlim = c(-1.5, 1.5), # Adjust x-axis limits for more space
               canvas.ylim = c(-1.5, 1.5)) # Adjust y-axis limits for more space
    # track.margin = c(0.01, 0.1), # Adjust track margins
    # track.height = 0.05) # Adjust track height
    
    # Create chord diagram
    chordDiagram(comparison_table, 
                 transparency = 0.5, 
                 grid.col = colour_vector,
                 annotationTrack = "grid",
                 preAllocateTracks = list(track.height = 0.1))
    
    # Add custom tracks and annotations
    circos.trackPlotRegion(track.index = 1, panel.fun = function(x, y) {
      xlim = get.cell.meta.data("xlim")
      ylim = get.cell.meta.data("ylim")
      sector.name = get.cell.meta.data("sector.index")
      circos.text(CELL_META$xcenter,
                  ylim[1] + cm_h(3), # Move the text further out
                  sector.name,
                  facing = "clockwise",
                  niceFacing = TRUE,
                  adj = c(0, 0.5))
      circos.axis(h = "bottom",
                  labels.cex = 0.6,
                  sector.index = sector.name)
    }, bg.border = NA)
    
    # Add the title
    title(paste(dataset_pair, collapse = " - "))
    
    # Draw sectors
    highlight.sector(rownames(comparison_table), 
                     track.index = 1, 
                     col = rgb(0, 0, 1, 0.3), # More opaque fill
                     border = NA) # Remove border
    highlight.sector(colnames(comparison_table), 
                     track.index = 1, 
                     col = rgb(1, 0, 0, 0.3), # More opaque fill
                     border = NA) # Remove border
    
    # Legend
    legend("right", 
           legend = dataset_pair, 
           fill = c(rgb(0, 0, 1, 0.3), rgb(1, 0, 0, 0.3)),
           border = NA,
           bty = "n", # No box around the legend
           cex = 1.2,
           x.intersp = 0.25, # Reduce horizontal spacing between legend boxes and text
           y.intersp = 0.75, # Reduce vertical spacing between legend lines
           inset = c(-0.1, -0.1)) # Move the legend further from the plot

